# (Permutations) For $n ≥ 2$,there are at least n subgroups of Sn of order $(n − 1)!$

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

For $n ≥ 2$, show that there are at least n subgroups of Sn of order $(n − 1)!$

Comment: Can you embed $S_{n-1}$ into $S_n$ in at least $n$ different ways?

Answer (score 1):

For $k \in \{1,..,n\}$, let 
$$H_k=\{ \sigma \in S_n | \sigma(k)=k \}$$
Then the subsets $H_1, .. H_n$ are subgroups of order $(n-1)!$ that are mutually distinct (I leave that to you to check).